# Как в стандартном примере раскрывающегося списка добавить элемент?

Tags: dart, flutter

Есть стандартный пример [ExpansionTile](https://flutter.io/catalog/samples/expansion-tile-sample/)

Как сделать, чтобы элементы третьего уровня Item A0.1 были в виде текста с чекбоксом (слева текст, справа - чекбокс)?

Answer (score 0):

Вместо [ListTile](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html) использовать [CheckboxListTile](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/CheckboxListTile-class.html)